# Divide int for best result

Tags: c#, formula

I am struggling a bit with this inside my head. I am trying to create a group creator which will create groups by its ultimate number.

The highest number which can be in a group is 4 and a group may be no less than 3 members unless the participant number is below 6.

Examples:

```
Participants: 5 = 1x3, 1x2
Participants: 7 = 1x4, 1x3
Participants: 8 = 2x4
Participants: 9 = 3x3
Participants: 10 = 1x4, 2x3
Participants: 18 = 3x4, 2x3
```

In short. 4 is best, 3 second best, 2 if necessary, 1 is a no go.

How can I create a formular in C# that get this? my mind is spinning around some kind of while loop but I am lost!

Here is what I doing right now, but I am not sure how to get there. I know that this is all wrong.

```
int participants = 10;

int g1 = 4;

while (participants > 0) {
    g1 = participants;
    participants -= 4;
}

print ("GROUP: " + g1);
```

Hoping for help and thanks in advance :-)

Comment: Why isn't 9 4,3,2?  Why isn't 10 4,4,2?  In short is it more important to avoid 2 than it is to have at least one 4?

Comment: I think you are having hard time because you do not really understand the problem or else you would have done a better job explaining it to us. I suggest you really get your head around the problem to really understand what the problem is. Then try it out with a loop or whatever you think you need. If you run into a problem, you will then have a specific question to ask here. Right now, your question is to basically do the work for you.

Comment: Yes, it is more important to avoid 2 than at least have 4.

Comment: @ CodingYoshi No, I underastand my own question perfectly, I just do not have a clue where to start. I am not asking you to solve this for me, I am asking for guidance in the right direction.

Comment: @Mansa that is what I did to point you in the right direction: `try it out with a loop or whatever you think you need. If you run into a problem, you will then have a specific question to ask here.` And I said your question is not clear. Both of them are helpful hints.

Answer (score 1):

If number `n` is *large enough* (say, `10` or more) your can try the scheme below:

```
    number           scheme
   ------------------------------------------
    n = 4k       ->  4k
    n = 4k + 1   ->  4(k - 2) + 3*3 
    n = 4k + 2   ->  4(k - 1) + 3*2
    n = 4k + 3   ->  4(k - 0) + 3*1
```

For instance when given

```
    n = 2017
```

we have

```
    n / 4 == 504
    n % 4 ==   1 // 4k + 1 case where k = 504
```

the solution is

```
    n = 4*502 + 3*3
```

So if number `n` is large you can guarantee that you have at most `3` second bests when all the others are best groups. For small `n`s `[2..9]` just build a dictionary of the best solutions.

Possible C# code:

```
 static Dictionary<int, string> s_LowNs = new Dictionary<int, string>() {
   {2, "1x2"},
   {3, "1x3"}, 
   ...
   {9, "3x3"},
 };

 private static string Solve(int value) {
   if (value <= 1)
     throw new ArgumentOutOfRange("value");

   string result;

   if (s_LowNs.TryGetValue(value, out result))
     return $"Participants: {value} = {result}";
   else {
     int k = value / 4;
     int c = value % 4;

     if (c == 0)   
       return $"Participants: {value} = {k}x4"; 
     else if (c == 1)   
       return $"Participants: {value} = {k - 2}x4 3x3"; 
     else if (c == 2)   
       return $"Participants: {value} = {k - 1}x4 2x3"; 
     else
       return $"Participants: {value} = {k}x4 1x3"; 
   }
 }
```